How to invert the selection while keeping the previous selection?
How can I select the same faces on the right side, which are selected on the left side? I know I can select the rest of the faces little by little with "shift", "c", or "b", but I would like to know if there is something easier, so I can apply it in future projects. Thanks in advance.


In the Select Menu you can find "Select Mirror" (Shift Ctrl M).
Tick the "Extend" option in the "Edit Last Operation" Tab (in the left bottom, a black box, F9 to recall it) if you want to add to the previous selection.


Omg, this really worked, thanks so much for your help! This setting was really hidden! Thanks again!
